# x-headers or custom email headers on Amazon SES using PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, amazon-ses, email-headers

I am trying to get custom email headers to work (x-header) , while not using the Amazon SDK , using curl.

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Date: '.$date;
$headers[] = 'Host: '.$this->ses->getHost();

$auth = 'AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId='.$this->ses->getAccessKey();
$auth .= ',Algorithm=HmacSHA256,Signature='.$this->__getSignature($date);
$headers[] = 'X-Amzn-Authorization: '.$auth;
```

trying to add this here.

```
$headers[] = 'X-CampaignId: ' . $campaignId
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

The headers keeps getting stripped out

are custom headers only supported with Amazon's SDK?
this article seems to indicate this:
http://www.techfounder.net/2011/03/23/mis-adventures-with-amazon-simple-email-services-ses/

using

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true)
```

this is what happens in curl

```
* About to connect() to email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com port 443
*   Trying <ip address>... * connected
* Connected to email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (<ip address>) port 443
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: <somefile>.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using RC4-MD5
* Server certificate:
*    subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com Inc./CN=email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
*    start date: 2013-07-17 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2014-07-18 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com matched
*    issuer: /C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
* SSL certificate verify ok.
&gt; POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: SimpleEmailService/php
Accept: */*
Date: Tue, 21 Jan 2014 19:25:04 UTC
Host: email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
X-Amzn-Authorization: <the key string>
X-CKCampaign: newYear2014
Comments: newYear2014
Return-Path: newYear2014
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 45171
Expect: 100-continue

&lt; HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
&lt; HTTP/1.1 200 OK
&lt; x-amzn-RequestId: <string>
&lt; Content-Type: text/xml
&lt; Content-Length: 326
&lt; Date: Tue, 21 Jan 2014 19:25:04 GMT
* Connection #0 to host email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

In the email the x-headers are gone

the return path header is replaced by

```
Return-Path: <longstring>@amazonses.com

    content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
boundary="----=_Part_<numbers>"
Date: Tue, 21 Jan 2014 19:14:17 +0000
Message-ID: <sting.amazonses.com>
X-SES-Outgoing: <string>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 21 Jan 2014 19:14:19.0370 (UTC) FILETIME=[FC02ECA0:01CF16DC]

------=_Part_<numbers>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Note : I have replaced some content with   etc

Comment: You're setting `$header[]` but passing `$headers` - typo maybe?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo here  not in my code, the amazon security key is also passed in through that array, and this key is required for the email to be sent, hence if that array was not passed correctly then the email send will fail. That is what bugs me , the amazon key is itself an x-header and i am trying to pass additional ones in the same way.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible to get it working with curl, you just gotta get the headers correct. As a last-resort you could sniff the request when using the SDK and compare when using curl. The article you linked to suggested that the Content-Length must be provided but I'm pretty sure curl adds this by default in this scenario.

Comment: I am not sure if amazon or the isp is stripping out the headers , i've added curl's debug data to the post, everything seems to be ok at PHPs end...